# Is there any difference in nutritional value between a wild caught fish and farmed fish?

Tags: fish

Is there any difference in nutritional value between a wild caught fish and farmed fish. In terms of calories, protein and most other nutrients?

Answer (score 1):

If they are of the same species and size, I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Up voted. At least substantially and  eccept for possible drugs like antibiotics. But it is not a real *nutritional* fact.